# Suds not working with python doing xml request

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, wsdl, suds

I am using suds 0.4 version with python 2.7. And the simple script does not work giving error "cannot import Client". Wher eis the problem?

```
import suds
from suds.client import Client

client = suds.Client("http://webservices.data-8.co.uk/companieshouse.asmx?WSDL")
result = client.service.GetCompanyDetails("username", "password", 1234)
print result.Status.Succes
```

Comment: Is this your exact code, copy/pasted? What is the exact error and stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're getting an error like `'module' object has no attribute 'Client'`.

You are calling `suds.Client()` which does not exist.

You have imported Client into your namespace on the line `from suds.client import Client`.

`suds` exists as a module, `Client` exists as a class, and `suds.client` exists as a module, but `suds.Client` does not exist. In your case you want to call the constructor `Client`, so...

Change your code to `client = Client(...)` and it will work if you have suds installed correctly.

Comment: changed code line as you recommended but still no fruits.. getting same error: cannot import name Client

Comment: found a problem. yours answer is correct, it works in that way but when i do run python from cmd line. however, when i run same script from Visual Studio Community 2013 it gives that weird error...Will create a new thread on it maybe someone had same problem

Comment: link to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030877/suds-cannot-import-name-client-in-ms-vs-community-2013-but-works-in-via-cmd